# how to run a series of codes repeatedly at a regular time interval until a condition is satisfied

Tags: vb.net

I want to run the series of codes continuously at a regular time interval and stop when a given condition is met

[image]

Comment: Put that in a `Do Until` loop...

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of looping or repetition, along with a timestamp check.

There are several options available in VB.Net:

---

### Use a Do Until or Do While loop with a delay

Example:

```
Do Until Now > [time]
    [code]
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep([delay in milliseconds])
Loop
```

**Advantage:** Reliable and simple.

**Disadvantage:** Ties up your processing, unless use some kind of multithreading, like a BackgroundWorker.

---

### Use a Timer

Example:

Inside the Timer.Tick Event:

```
If Now < [time]
    [code]
Else
    Timer.Enabled = False
End If
```

**Advantage:** Simple and does not tie up your main thread.

**Disadvantage:** Sometimes can skip ticks.